# Cakephp retrieving data from database

Tags: php, cakephp, database-design

I'm having trouble modeling my database. Currently it looks like this (I'm hiding the irrelevant fields): https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsMt6.png

It is working fine, for example, when I want it to return a list of all the servers:

```
$this->Server->find('all');
```

It returns an array with the right information:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Array (...)
            [User] => Array (...)
            [Highlight] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 39
                            [id_server] => 8
                            [id_highlight] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 40
                            [id_server] => 8
                            [id_highlight] => 5
                        )

                )
            [SubServer] => Array(...)

        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Array (...)
            [User] => Array (...)
            [Highlight] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 41
                            [id_server] => 10
                            [id_highlight] => 4
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 42
                            [id_server] => 10
                            [id_highlight] => 5
                        )

                )
            [SubServer] => Array(...)

        )
)
```

In short, each game "server" has some kind of higlights pointed by the user. Like "Anti-cheat system", "Active staff", "Custom events", etc. Each of these highlights have an id and a name.

Is there a way to grab the **name** from the table **highlight_names** corresponding to each of the **highlights.id_hightlight** (and the rest of the data, like the array above) using Model::find()?

Comment: Does your Highlight model belongsTo HighlightName model? You can either play around with the `recursive` value or (IMHO the preferred method) use the [containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) to explicitly identify all models and fields you want returns

Comment: I managed to do it with Containable. Thank you.